# timeIntervalSinceDate in past?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm creating a NSDate in the past (1 hour in the past) and that looks to be setting correct, only thing is I want to then use that to determine if an even has happened or not. Because I set to be in the past, when I do the check it should definitely think the even has happened, but timeIntervalSinceDate seems to only give a positive result?

This is the code I'm using with timeIntervalSinceDate

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
  NSTimeInterval secondsSincePlantingInterval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:plantingDate];
```

Which is giving 68 seconds, but it should be -68 seconds, or does it not return negative values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does return negative values, yes. But if `plantingDate` is in the past then I'd expect `secondsSincePlantingInterval` to be positive.

If you think about it, that line is reading:

> Tell me the number of seconds `now` is *since* `plantingDate`.

Just like Tuesday 2nd is one day since Monday 1st, `now` is +ve seconds since `plantingDate`.

You want:

```
NSTimeInterval secondsSincePlantingInterval = [plantingDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

Comment: I just switched the Now with the planting date, seems to work as well :)

Comment: Of course. I just showed the use of the `timeIntervalSinceNow` method since you then don't need to create your own "now" variable.

Answer (score 5):

This is perfectly normal, documented behavior

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states :

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

> **Return Value**
>
> The interval between the receiver and anotherDate. If the receiver is earlier than anotherDate, the return value is negative.

Since `plantingDate` is in the past, the receiver is **not** earlier than it. Therefore the value is positive.

Moreover ; this is plain english

```
 [now timeIntervalSinceDate:plantingDate];
```

So, the time interval since the plantingDate up to now is positive.